# Does Coverity's REST API have way to get issues per project and stream?

Tags: rest, coverity

I wanted to get results from Coverity's REST API. 
In the documentation, it states i can access

```
> api/viewContents/<type>/v1/<View Name>?projectId=<project> ID>&rowCount=-1
```

I didn't find any information if I can add more parameters such as streamID.
Is there any way to achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create different views for the user with whose credentials you are making the restapi call.
The views will look under the streams you are interested in(You would get an option to select the stream in the view edit settings). You should then be able to use the view id to get the results for the stream you need.